# How to distinguish between the first and rest for duplicate records using sql?

Tags: sql

These are the input table and required output table.

```
                                  Input table 

ID  Name 
-------------
1   aaa
1   ababaa
2   bbbbbb
2   bcbcbccbc
2   bcdbcdbbbbb
3   ccccc
```

```
                                 Output table 

ID  Name        Ord
-----------------------------
1   aaa         first
1   ababaa      rest    
2   bbbbbb      first   
2   bcbcbccbc   rest    
2   bcdbcdbbbbb rest
3   ccccc       first
```

First and Rest is based on the occurrence of an ID field.

Is there a way to write a SQL query to achieve this ?

P.S. - This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645849/sql-suppressing-duplicate-adjacent-records) is somewhat similar to what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try this

```
SELECT id, name,  
Decode(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by id order by id,name),1,'First','Rest') Ord
FROM Input_table;
```

You can use this query as this is much simple and yields good performance

Comment: As this query was using row_number function and there are no inline views

Answer (score 2):

```
select id, name, case rnk when 1 then 'first' else 'rest' end ord
from(
select *, RANK() over(partition by id order by id,name) rnk  
from input
) X
```